# Relação genérica entre model LogEntry

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Alguém já trabalhou com o Auditlog no django ? [Documentação do Django AuditLog](https://django-auditlog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Digamos que tenho esse modelo:

```
class Cadastro(models.Model):
    nome = models..TextField()

auditlog.register(Cadastro)
```

Gostaria de um queryset que retornasse todos os registro da tabela Cadastro juntamente com os atributos do auditlog.
Pelas minhas pesquisas, daria para criar um atributo ForeignKey genérico no model Cadastro  para linkar com a tabela de Logs, porém ainda não consegui achar uma solução.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Rodolfo, o que é AuditLog? É um pacote (tipo [esse](https://github.com/vvangelovski/django-audit-log) ou [esse](https://github.com/jjkester/django-auditlog/))? É o [LogEntry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects) do Django Admin? Seria legal você [edit] sua pergunta e esclarecer estes pontos (de preferência usando a tag do módulo que você está usando)

Comment: @fernandosavio é segundo link que vc postou, add um link para ficar claro. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte:

```
from auditlog.models import LogEntry
from auditlog.registry import auditlog
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class Cadastro(models.Model):
nome = models..TextField()
log = GenericRelation(LogEntry)
```